# Unable to print the bibliography with memoir

Tags: bibtex

I have the following layout in my document:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[paper=letterpaper]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsbsy}

\begin{document}
\DoubleSpacing
\maxtocdepth{subparagraph} % put everything into the ToC
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{XX}
\input{X}
\input{Y}
\input{Z}   
\bibliography{thesis_bibliography.bib}
\end{document}
```

I can see that WinEdt parses the bibliography correctly (the cited entries show up on the left menu), and `PDFTeXify` (provided by WinEdt) has always compiled my document correctly including the bibliography.

Why can't I print the bibliography?

### Update:

1. My citations are of the form `~\cite` or `\cite` and my entries in the file `thesis_bibliography.bib` are of the form: `@inproceedings`, `@article`, etc.
2. I noticed LaTeX complains because it thinks my bibliography is in a file called `thesis.bbl`, but above I have a line that says `\bibliography{thesis_bibliography.bib}`. Why does it think it's the wrong file?

Comment: Please indicate whether you use a citation-manager package (such as `cite` and `natbib`) and any citation commands other than `\cite`.

Comment: Use `\bibliography{thesis_bibliography}` not `\bibliography{thesis_bibliography.bib}`, the extention is implied. This should also be indicated in the `.blg` file, i.e. the `bibtex` log

Comment: Thanks @daleif. I did that but the problem persists.

Comment: Then please post a full minimal example including sample bibtex data. Working with sniplets is tedious. Do you even have `splncs.bst`? My system does not know it. What are the exact errors you get? Remember that `file.bib` is _not_ your bibliography. It is the data for `bibtex`. Thus what LaTeX read is `thesis.bbl` which is the output from `bibtex`. Do you even run `bibtex`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't provided a compilable MWE, so it's not possible to be sure what's going on. In an earlier version of your posting, you had the line

```
\bibliographystyle{splncs}
```

in the code. However, the file `splncs.bst` does not appear to be a part of either the TeXlive2011 or the MikTeX2.9 distribution, and it's not on the CTAN either. Assuming that no such file is present in your TeX distribution, this would explain why no bibliography is being generated. (Have you checked your log file for any complaints about a nonexistent style file?) Conversely, if I add the line `\documentclass{memoir}` to the top of your code as well as something like `\bibliographystyle{plain}` and a couple of dummy citation commands, your code (minus the three `\input` statements, of course) has no difficulty in creating a bibliography.

In short, I suggest you either locate the file `splncs.bst` somewhere on the 'net and install it on your system or use a different bibliography style file altogether.

Comment: Thank you @Mico. You are right. The problem was that the `.bst` file was missing. When I removed the line `\bibliographystyle` I noticed I was still unable to compile my code, so I updated the question. But I now realize that I need to specify a `\bibliographystile`. So in conclusion, the problem has nothing to do with WinEdt, memoir or anything, I was just not using the bibliography commands properly.